# Spring Cache is not being populated in test

Tags: spring-boot, caching

I have the following test which is trying to assert that data has been added to spring cache.

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainSpringApplication.class)
class NamesServiceCacheTest {

    @Mock
    ApiClient apiClientMock;

    NamesServiceImpl sut;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        sut = new NamesServiceImpl(apiClientMock);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
            List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<>();
            caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache("namesCache"));
            cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
            return cacheManager;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testResponseGoesIntoCache() {
        when(apiClientMock.getNamesFromXApi()).thenReturn(getMockedResponse());
        sut.getNames();
        var cache = cacheManager.getCache("namesCache"); //<--- if I debug here, the cache is empty
        assertEquals(getMockedResponse(), cache.get("namesCache").get());
    }
```

However, with this test nothing is added to the cache. Is this because I'm not loading the cacheManager on the spring context correctly?

Is it due to the `extends CachingConfigurerSupport` which is on the config (see below)?

Here is the rest of the config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<>();
        caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache("namesCache"));
        cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

And the service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NamesServiceImpl implements NameService {

    private final ApiClient apiClient;

    @Override
    @Cacheable("namesCache")
    public Mono<GetInstitutionsResponse> getNames()() {
        return apiClient.getNamesFromXApi();
    }

}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why do you need `static class Config {` in your test ?. 
If you put a breakpoint `public CacheManager cacheManager()` does it go there ?
Try put `@EnableCaching` at the class level `NamesServiceCacheTest`

Comment: Yep break point on that line never hits, so the config was pointless. I tried adding the annotation to the class, but same result. Thanks